# Ruby precedence of methods in objects extended with multiple modules

Tags: ruby, module, dci

Given the following:

```
class User; attr_accessor :roles; end

module RegisteredUser
  def default_context
    Submission
  end
end

module Admin
  def default_context
    Review
  end
end

current_user = User.new
current_user.roles = ["registered_user", "admin"]
current_user.roles.each do |role|
  role_module = role.gsub(/ /, '_').camelize
  if module_exists?(role_module)
    current_user.extend role_module.constantize
  end
end
context = self.extend current_user.default_context
```

Is there a way to set the priority of `User#default_context`? That is, can I say that the `Admin#default_context` always takes priority over `RegisteredUser#default_context` regardless of the order in which `current_user` is extended?

Comment: You might be able to do something with `extended` or `method_added`, but you'd need to have some sort of priority rules mechanism either in the modules or somewhere... erm... else.

Comment: I can't find either of those methods in ruby doc.

Comment: Moved to pseudo-answer for formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method_added` is in `Module`.

I actually meant `included`, not `extended`, but both are also in `Module`.

The mechanism would revolve around doing something like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(FooMethods)
  end

  module FooMethods
    def bar
      # Whatever
    end
  end
end
```

Inside `Foo.included` you can determine, based on arbitrary criteria, whether or not the methods in question should be added to `base` (the entity including the module).

In your case, you could check to see if a "higher priority" module was already included, or see if the module *is* the "higher priority" module. Based on that you'd decide whether or not to add the methods.

Comment: I get "NoMethodError: private method `method_added' called for Foo:Module" when I try Foo.method_added.

Comment: @ReedG.Law That's not how you'd use it, nor am I convinced it's what you'd want to use--I think it's an "after" hook, which doesn't help. `included` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Since an Admin is also a RegisteredUser, I would do

```
module Admin
  include RegisteredUser
  ...
end
```

and then only

```
current_user.extend Admin
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way. If Admin and RegisteredUser were classes, it would make sense making Admin inherit from RegisteredUser. In case of modules, dunno.

Comment: This method seems to work. The only drawback I can see is if there were many modules and complex combinations (i.e. a user who is an admin but not an editor, but Admin includes Editor).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot; in Ruby the order of module inclusion is the order in which modules are searched ([after the current class, before parent classes](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png)). The only way to change the 'priority' is to include the modules in the order you want, or to move them to a parent class.

Although not pure Ruby, you can use the [Remix](https://github.com/banister/remix) library by banisterfiend to change module ordering (or unmixin a module, or...other things).

Comment: I'd have to play, but it sure seems like some hooks into `included`/`extended` could be used to do this, no?

Comment: Remix looks good, but it's hard to jump to that kind of solution without further evaluation. Although that kind of functionality could be essential to using the DCI design pattern.